# Add autoincrement column that is not primary key Alembic

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, alembic

I want to add a column that is autoincrement that is not primary key to an existing MySQL database.

The command issued on the server required for this operation is the following:

```
ALTER TABLE `mytable` ADD `id` INT UNIQUE NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST
```

The issue I face is how to replicate this table change through an Alembic migration. I have tried:

```
from alembic import op
import sqlalchemy as sa

def upgrade():
    op.add_column('mytable', sa.Colummn('id', sa.INTEGER(), 
                  nullable=False, autoincrement=True)
```

but when I try to insert a row with the following command:

```
INSERT INTO `mytable` (`col1`, `col2`) VALUES (`bar`);
```

where `col1`, `col2` are non nullable columns. When I insert this record I expect the table to generate automatically the id for me.

```
ERROR 1364 (HY000): Field 'id' doesn't have a default value
```

If I inspect the sql autogenerated by Alembic using the following command:

```
alembic upgrade 'hash-of-revision' --sql
```

it spits out, for the given revision:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD COLUMN id INTEGER NOT NULL;
```

Which means that either Alembic or SQLAlchemy is ignoring the `autoincrement` field when generating the sql of the migration.

Is there a way I can solve this? Or can I establish a migration based on a custom sql command?

Comment: Doesn't `sa.Colummn('mytable',....` result in a column called 'mytable', not 'id'?

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo when transcribing the example to the SO question, that is not the problem however

Comment: I have added more information regarding how I insert and how migrations are generated

Comment: Have you tried passing the `autoincrement=True` flag to `op.add_column()`: http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/ops.html#alembic.operations.Operations.alter_column.params.autoincrement. As it is you pass it to the SQLA `Column`.

Comment: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.autoincrement See the section starting with "The setting only has an effect for columns which are: ..." The way I read that, it's behaving as expected, since your new column doesn't meet the stated criteria.

Comment: I read the docs I linked hastily: It's alter, not add. Though one could chain the 2 ops, perhaps, so after adding the column, use alembic's alter.

Answer (score 3):

First we add the column and allow it to have null values

`op.add_column('abc', Column('id', BIGINT(unsigned=True), comment='This column stores the type of phrase') )`

Then we create the primary key

`op.create_primary_key( 'abc_pk', table_name='abc', columns=['id'] )`

Not sure how it allows me to add a primary key on an empty column but i guess it is because it is in a transaction block.

Then we alter the column to have the autoincrement column

`op.alter_column( existing_type=BIGINT(unsigned=True), table_name='abc', column_name='id', autoincrement=True, existing_autoincrement=True, nullable=False)`

Answer (score 2):

As of SQLAlchemy 1.4+ and Alembic 1.9 you can use the Identity type, which according to [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/postgresql.html#postgresql-10-and-above-identity-columns), supersedes the Serial type.

This Declarative ORM:

```
class ProductOption(Base):
    __tablename__:str = 'product_options'

    id:Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, server_default=Identity(start=1, cycle=True), primary_key=True)
    uuid:Mapped[UUID] = mapped_column(UUID, nullable=False, unique=True)
    name:Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(50), nullable=False)
    price:Mapped[Decimal] = mapped_column(Numeric(16, 4), nullable=False)
    cost:Mapped[Decimal] = mapped_column(Numeric(16, 4), nullable=False)
    unit:Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(8), nullable=False)
    duration:Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer)
```

Results in the following Alebic `--autogenerate` migration:

```
op.create_table(
    "product_options",
    sa.Column(
        "id",
        sa.Integer(),
        sa.Identity(always=False, start=1, cycle=True),
        nullable=False,
    ),
    sa.Column("uuid", sa.UUID(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column("name", sa.String(length=50), nullable=False),
    sa.Column("price", sa.Numeric(precision=16, scale=4), nullable=False),
    sa.Column("cost", sa.Numeric(precision=16, scale=4), nullable=False),
    sa.Column("unit", sa.String(length=8), nullable=False),
    sa.Column("duration", sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
    sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint("id"),
    sa.UniqueConstraint("uuid"),
)
```